# Why does MongoDB maven dependency cannot be added with runtime scope?

Tags: java, mongodb, maven, maven-plugin

Why does MongoDB maven dependency cannot be added as `runtime` whereas for all the other databases it works without any issues ?

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
    <version>7.0</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Please guide.

Comment: What issue do you have when try to add runtime dependency?

Comment: The IDE (NetBeans) marks all the class usages as "red" which indicates that it cannot find the classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because for oracle you use the `jdbc` API which oracle only implement (unless you are using oracle SQL types for example).

You are only using The `Connection`, `Statement`, `ResultSet`  and in runtime you obtain an Oracle Connection, probably using a container managed connection pool.

You don't compile your code (again, usually) with classes taken from `ojdbc7` jar. The `jdbc` interfaces and classes are part of the jre.

Whereas with mongodb, you code and compile with specific classes and interfaces taken from the `mongo-java-driver` jar (and jars it depends on). Classes such as `MongoClient`, `Document` etc.